# The missing De Morgan's law

Tags: coq, demorgans-law

Coq uses constructive logic, which means that if you try to fill out
De Morgan's laws, you'll end up missing 2.
Namely, you can't prove:

```
Theorem deMorgan_nand P Q (andPQ : ~(P /\ Q)) : P \/ Q.
Abort.

Theorem deMorgan_nall {A} (P : A -> Prop) (allPa : ~forall a, P a) : exists a, ~P a.
Abort.
```

This makes sense, because you've have to compute whether it was
the left or right item of the `or`, which you can't do in general.

Looking at
"Classical Mathematics for a Constructive World"
(https://arxiv.org/pdf/1008.1213.pdf)
has the definitions

```
Definition orW P Q := ~(~P /\ ~Q).
Definition exW {A} (P : A -> Prop) := ~forall a, ~P a.
```

similar to De Morgan's law.  This suggests an alternative formulation.

```
Theorem deMorgan_nand P Q (andPQ : ~(P /\ Q)) : orW (~P) (~Q).
  hnf; intros nnPQ; destruct nnPQ as [ nnP nnQ ].
  apply nnP; clear nnP; hnf; intros p.
  apply nnQ; clear nnQ; hnf; intros q.
  apply (andPQ (conj p q)).  
Qed.

Theorem deMorgan_nall {A} (P : A -> Prop) (allPa : ~forall a, P a) : exW (fun a => ~P a).
Abort.
```

But, it doesn't work with negating forall.  In particular, it gets stuck on
trying to convert `~~P a` into `P a`.  So, despite in the nand case
converting `~~P` into `P`, it doesn't seem to work with forall.
You can also show that there is some element of `a` that has
`P a`.

Similarly, you could try to show

```
Theorem deMorgan_nexn {A} (P : A -> Prop) (exPa : ~exists a, ~P a) : ~~forall a, P a.
Abort.
```

but that gets stuck in that once you have the argument `a`,
the conclusion is no longer `False`, so you can't use `~~P -> P`.

So, if you can't prove `deMorgan_nall`, is there any theorem like it?
Or is `~forall a, P a` already as simplified as it can get?
More generally, when the conclusion is `False`, that allows for using
the law of excluded middle (`P \/ ~P`).  Is there any counterpart
to that that works when the proposition takes an argument, that is
`P : A -> Prop` instead of `P : Prop` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The principle you are looking for is known as [*double negation shift*](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/double-negation+shift). It is *not* valid in intuitionistic logic in general. Despite looking fairly innocuous at first, as its conclusion is a doubly-negated formula, it is actually quite potent. Indeed, DNS is essentially what is needed in order to interpret the axiom of choice through the double-negation translation.

**Edit by scubed:**

So, that means I have to add an axiom to handle this case.  Using the axiom,

```
Axiom deMorgan_allnn : forall {A} (P : A -> Prop) (allPa : forall a, ~~P a), ~~forall a, P a.

Theorem deMorgan_nall {A} (P : A -> Prop) (allPa : ~forall a, P a) : exW (fun a => ~P a).
  hnf; intros ex1; apply deMorgan_allnn in ex1.
  apply ex1; clear ex1; hnf; intros all2.
  apply (allPa all2).
Qed.
```